# After using split() for all lines in a text file, my intention was to add ', ' to every line right before the very last element

Tags: python, python-2.7

but the result looks like elements in a list.
I discovered online `[:-1]` which gives me a text file similar to as follows:

```
['Whitley'], in
['Oconto'], wi
['Nicholas'], wv
['Kanabec'], mn
['Van', 'Buren'], tn
```

I assume there is a better way that doesn't involve writing to the file what looks like elements in a list, with the brackets, apostrophes, and commas?

The code I have is:

```
fp = open('file1.txt')

pairs = [line.split() for line in fp]

fp.close()

fp = open('file2.txt', 'w')

for pair in pairs:
    string = str(pair[:-1]) + ', ' + str(pair[-1]) + '\n'
    fp.write(string)

fp.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified, including desired and actual output.

Comment: How does the input file look and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
with open('file1.txt') as fp:
    lines = [', '.join(line.rsplit(' ',1)) for line in fp]
with open('file2.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for line in lines:
        fp.write(line)
```